# Merge columns and fill the empty space with the merged data using Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to merge 38 to 36, 45 to 43, and 79 to 78 filling in the empty space on the merging column.

Dataset

|  | 0 | 5 | 36 | 38 | 43 | 45 | 78 | 79 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01JUN2022 |  | 1.2 |  | B |  | 1.2 |
| 2 | C | 01JUN2022 |  | 1.4 |  | D |  | 1.4 |
| 3 | E | 01JUN2022 | 1.5 |  | F |  | 1.6 |  |
| 4 | G | 01JUN2022 | 1.7 |  | H |  | 1.7 |  |
| 5 | I | 01JUN2022 | 1.4 |  | J |  | 1.8 |  |
| 6 | K | 01JUN2022 | 1.7 |  | L |  | 1.3 |  |

Required output

|  | 0 | 5 | 36 | 43 | 79 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01JUN2022 | 1.2 | B | 1.2 |
| 2 | C | 01JUN2022 | 1.4 | D | 1.4 |
| 3 | E | 01JUN2022 | 1.5 | F | 1.6 |
| 4 | G | 01JUN2022 | 1.7 | H | 1.7 |
| 5 | I | 01JUN2022 | 1.4 | J | 1.8 |
| 6 | K | 01JUN2022 | 1.7 | L | 1.3 |

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the columns and [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
# assuming the values are integer
# for string use {'38': '36'...}
merge = {38: 36, 45: 43, 78: 79}

out = df.rename(columns=merge).groupby(level=0, axis=1).first()
```

output:

```
  0          5    36 43   79
1  A  01JUN2022  1.2  B  1.2
2  C  01JUN2022  1.4  D  1.4
3  E  01JUN2022  1.5  F  1.6
4  G  01JUN2022  1.7  H  1.7
5  I  01JUN2022  1.4  J  1.8
6  K  01JUN2022  1.7  L  1.3
```

Comment: Refer to the image attached. I'm not getting the output and also losing the data. Please be kind enough to check and advice.

Comment: You don't provide a reproducible input, so I'm not sure what doesn't work as you want. Screenshots are not helping. You seem to want to do complex modification in Excel, which was not at all your initial question.

Comment: Hi. I'm taking data from a txt file to a dataframe and trying to export it into excel.

Comment: Can you provide the text file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1CRzCMRo_TV2B-6ZDPA0kb7S7DGuDg7IY

Comment: I can't access it, please update your question with its content, or if really big use a public pastebin

Comment: sorry about it. access given

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
df[36] = df[[36,38]].sum(axis=1)
df[43] = df.apply(lambda x: x[43] if pd.isna(x[45]) else x[45],axis=1)
df[79] = df[[78,79]].sum(axis=1)

df.drop([38,45,78],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on [`pandas.DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df.iloc[:, 0:2].join(
   [df[x[0]].combine_first(df[x[1]]) for x in zip([36,43,78], [38,45,79])])
```

Output:

```
   0          5   36 43   78
0  A  01JUN2022  1.2  B  1.2
1  C  01JUN2022  1.4  D  1.4
2  E  01JUN2022  1.5  F  1.6
3  G  01JUN2022  1.7  H  1.7
4  I  01JUN2022  1.4  J  1.8
5  K  01JUN2022  1.7  L  1.3
```

---

Alternatively:

```
idx = [36, 43, 78]
df.iloc[:, 0:2].join(df.loc[:, idx].combine_first(
    df.loc[:, [38, 45, 79]].set_axis(idx, axis=1)))
```

Comment: I'm getting an Indentation error: unexpected incident

Comment: values are integer

Comment: I got them as strings after having imported your dataset, @Dhakshika!

Comment: I have just updated my solution accordingly, @Dhakshika.